# How to retain and increase the value of variable in SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Initially, I have two variables x (group variable) and y, now I'd like to create a third variable z which within each group of x starts from 1 and increase by 1 whenever y changes. Please see the following example. Could someone help how I can realize it in sql server 2008?

Thanks a lot!

```
x: a a a a a a a a b b b b b b b b
y: 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 3 0 1 0 0 2 3 0 0
```

Finally, I'd like to create z like this:

```
x: a a a a a a a a b b b b b b b b
y: 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 3 0 1 0 0 2 3 0 0
z: 1 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6
```

Comment: [SQL Fiddle for this problem](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7163/8/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple solution:

```
  declare @temp table ([row] int identity,[x] char,[y] int)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('a',0)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('a',0)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('a',0)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('a',1)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('a',0)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('a',0)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('a',2)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('a',3)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('b',0)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('b',1)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('b',0)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('b',0)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('b',2)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('b',3)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('b',0)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('b',0)

--select * from @temp 

DECLARE @int int=0
;WITH CTE as(
select *,1 as incr from @temp where row=1 
union all
select t.*,
CASE WHEN t.x=c.x then CASE WHEN t.y=c.y then incr else incr+1 end else CASE WHEN t.y=c.y then @int else @int+1 end end as incr
from @temp t inner join CTE c
on t.row=c.row+1
)

select * from CTE
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and `row_number` something like this.

```
with C1 as
(
  select T1.id,
         T1.x,
         T1.y,
         row_number() over (partition by T1.x order by T1.id) as rn
  from table1 as T1
), C2 as
(
  select C1.id,
         C1.x,
         C1.y,
         C1.rn,
         1 as z
  from C1
  where C1.rn = 1
  union all
  select C1.id,
         C1.x,
         C1.y,
         C1.rn,
         C2.z + case when C1.y <> C2.y then 1 else 0 end
  from C1 
    inner join C2
      on C1.x = C2.x and
         C1.rn = C2.rn + 1
)
select x, y, z
from C2
order by id
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Note that using a CTE as the source for a recursive query can have some issues with performance. If that s the case I would recommend you to put the result of the CTE `C1` in a temporary table with a primary key on `(x, rn)`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7163/9/0)

Answer (score 1):

You can't quite do this with `row_number() over (partition by ... order by ...)` and a `CTE` query doesn't seem to work either.  I like to avoid using cursors whenever possible, but a cursor may be the very thing for your situation:

```
declare @tbl table (id int, x char(1), y int, z int null)

declare
  @id int, @x char(1), @y int,
  @x2 char(1) = null, @y2 int = null, @z int

insert into @tbl (id, x, y) values
(1, 'a', 0), (2, 'a', 0), (3, 'a', 0),
(4, 'a', 1),
(5, 'a', 0), (6, 'a', 0),
(7, 'a', 2),
(8, 'a', 3),
(9, 'b', 0),
(10, 'b', 1),
(11, 'b', 0), (12, 'b', 0),
(13, 'b', 2),
(14, 'b', 3),
(15, 'b', 0), (16, 'b', 0)

declare cr cursor for
  select id, x, y
  from   @tbl
  order by  id

open cr
fetch next from cr into @id, @x, @y

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  set @z =
    case when @x2 is null or @x <> @x2
      then 1
      else
        case when @y = @y2
          then @z
          else @z + 1
        end
    end

  update @tbl
  set    z = @z
  where  id = @id

  set @x2 = @x
  set @y2 = @y

  fetch next from cr into @id, @x, @y
end

close cr
deallocate cr

select x, y, z
from   @tbl
order by id
```

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd throw my solution into the mix:

```
declare @temp table ([row] int identity,[x] char,[y] int)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('a',0)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('a',0)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('a',0)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('a',1)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('a',0)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('a',0)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('a',2)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('a',3)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('b',0)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('b',1)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('b',0)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('b',0)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('b',2)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('b',3)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('b',0)
insert into @temp([x],[y]) values ('b',0)


declare @temp1 table
(
 [row] int
,[x] char
,[y] int
,[change] int
)
insert into @temp1
(
 [row]
,[x]
,[y]
,[change]
)
select 
 [t1].[row]
,[t1].[x]
,[t1].[y] 
,iif([t1].[x] = [t2].[x] and [t1].[y] <> [t2].[y],1,0) [change]
from @temp [t1]
left join @temp [t2] on [t2].[row] = [t1].[row] - 1

select * from @temp1

select 
 [row]
,[x]
,[y]
,(select sum([change]) from @temp1 [t2] where [t2].[row] <= [t1].[row] and [t2].[x] = [t1].[x]) + 1 [z]
from @temp1 [t1]
```